# Abstract class 'ExcelWriter' with abstract methods instantiatedpylint(abstract-class-instantiated)

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, dataframe

Estou tentando salvar alguns DataFrames em um arquivo excel porem o mesmo esta dando erro, vi alguns tutoriais e mesmo deixando idêntico ainda continua dando erro.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer: 
    dCliente.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_CLIENTES', index=False)
    dProjeto.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_PROJETOS', index=False)
    dTask.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_TAREFAS', index=False)
    fFATO.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='FATO', index=False)
    dUsers.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_USUARIOS', index=False)
    xlswriter.save() 
    xlswriter.close()
```

e esse é o erro que aparece.
Abstract class 'ExcelWriter' with abstract methods instantiatedpylint(abstract-class-instantiated)

grato pelas respostas.

Comment: pq não usa `df.to_excel`?

Comment: tem a possibilidade de salvar em varias abas ??

Comment: sim, veja a documentação: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como a [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) diz, quando se deseja salvar mais de um sheet no mesmo arquivo é necessário declarar o objeto ExcelWriter

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('teste.xlsx') as writer:  
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df2')
```

No seu caso

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer: 
    dCliente.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_CLIENTES', index=False)
    dProjeto.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_PROJETOS', index=False)
    dTask.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_TAREFAS', index=False)
    fFATO.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='FATO', index=False)
    dUsers.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_USUARIOS', index=False)
```

Você pode definir outra engine dessa forma

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer: 
    dCliente.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_CLIENTES', index=False)
    dProjeto.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_PROJETOS', index=False)
    dTask.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_TAREFAS', index=False)
    fFATO.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='FATO', index=False)
    dUsers.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DIM_USUARIOS', index=False)
```

---

No seu código você atribui ao objeto writer, dessa forma: `writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:`

---

Utilizando with, você garante que o objeto seja aberto e fechado corretamente sendo desnecessário `xlswriter.close()`, uma vez que ele nem contem o método close. O nome certo é xlsxwriter, e só acessando o workbook você consegue utilizar o .close ou .save.

Exemplo retirado da documentação:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook  = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello Excel')

workbook.close()
```